# Rootlayout navbar and footder still showing at the DashboardLayout after the user login in app router nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, firebase-authentication, next.js13, app-router, authprovider

I am working on a project using the nextjs app router where I have a dashboardlayout inside the dashboard folder  that only login user can access but the Rootlayout navbar and footer still show at the dashboardlayout after login. how can I fix this. where can wrap the application with AuthProvider from context and firbase for auth

Comment: Can you post an image of your project structure?

Comment: are you using getLayout ?

Comment: https://github.com/Akanscode/sky_fitness_hub   link to the github

Answer (score 1):

That is intended behavior of Next JS layouts. If you don't want the RootLayout's navbar and footer to apply to all pages then you shouldn't put it there. You should only apply that layout to the pages that you are using it on.